# how to reorder a bootstrap responsive layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

How can I accomplish the following layout, so that on mobile-sized screens (xs columns) we have the below:

[image]

but on non-xs columns we have:

[image]

Note that block #3 has to be pulled up to be right below block #1 on non-xs sizes (which means it probably can't share the same row as block #4).  Here's the closest I can get given the above constraint:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Block #2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
      Block #1 - Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Block #4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
      Block #3 - Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you need to look into pull and push. https://scotch.io/tutorials/reorder-css-columns-using-bootstrap

Comment: On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Comment: @Rob can you please undo your vote to close this question and undo your downvote because I added some code as requested?  thanks.

Comment: I did not downvote. There are 8000 to 10,000 questions asked on SO every day. It's hard to say who downvotes so it's never worth asking any one person about it.

Answer (score 1):

The example you provided defies the nature of the single dimension grid that flex was intended for. I would recommend that you use [css grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) if you wish to create a template that accepts responsive, 2-dimensional layouts like your example.

If you want to come close to your example, you can set the flex order to reverse https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#direction.

Then you can include classes for each media query:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row flex-row-reverse">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">1</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">2</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3">3</div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try it out by resizing your browser:

- Bootstrap v3 - https://codepen.io/doppl3r/pen/ppBXEe?editors=1100
- Bootstrap v4 - https://codepen.io/doppl3r/pen/vpMwrz?editors=1100

Comment: unfortunately I am limited to a bootstrap 3 solution

Comment: I'll edit and add an example for v3, this example uses Nate's recommended 'push' & 'pull' technique

Comment: I appreciate the effort, however if you add `style="min-height:70px;"` to the "2" block, you'll see that the "3" block doesn't lift up to right below the "1" block.

Comment: I agree, that's exactly what having a 1-dimension grid will do. Think of 'CSS Flex' like building a brick wall. The bricks must be stacked in a single line to avoid falling over. 'CSS Grid' on the other hand, is like placing custom shaped tiles on the ground. You can easily fit your pieces wherever your floor plan will let you.

Comment: It's good advice.  Unfortunately, we must support older browsers :(

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can serve two different webpages with jQuery!

```
// on page load, determine h/w ratio to determine whether mobile device
// or not and redirect accordingly
$(document).ready(function() {
  let h = window.screen.height;
  let w = window.screen.width;
  // for mobile resolutions
  if ((h/w) > 1.0) {
    window.location.replace("www.example1.com");
  } 
  // for non-mobile resolutions
  else {
    window.location.replace("www.example2.com");
  }
});
```

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the (off topic) question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your solution creates more problems for the developer. Why would you want to serve 2 near-identical websites depending on the device when you can provide 1 website that responsively adapts to the user's view?

Answer (score 0):

You can use column reordering in bootstrap 4!
See this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/layout/grid/#reordering

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 order-2 order-lg-1 order-xl-1" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Block #2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-1 order-lg-2 order-xl-2" style="background-color:pink;">
      Block #1 - Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9 order-4 order-lg-3 order-xl-3" style="background-color:yellow;">
      Block #4 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br>
      Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 order-3 order-lg-4 order-xl-4" style="background-color:pink;">
      Block #3 - Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```